# ctrl+shift+e causes beeping

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, input

I recently got a new laptop and installed Arch on it.  I noticed that in a few applications, including chrome and gedit, pressing ctrl+shift+e will cause the next few keys pressed to be underlined, beep when pressed, and then deleted.

I've looked around for a while, and the only way I can seem to "fix" it is to unload the `pcspkr` module.  However, this still doesn't fix the issue, it only silences the beeping.

It seems to happen under both gnome and i3, but not in a tty.

Is there any way I can turn this off?

[Video of the behavior](https://youtu.be/ngA8pGsxPrw)

Comment: Is there a reason you keep pressing this particular key combination?

Comment: In Google docs, pressing ctrl+shift+e is supposed to center the text. Instead, it does this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seee https://askubuntu.com/a/1039039

> One needs to run `ibus-setup` and in the tab "Emoji" change the shortcut (click on the three dots that are focused in the screenshot)

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkIMContextSimple.html) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20171016072955/https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkIMContextSimple.html)), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> is a key-combination offered by Gnome's input method to input an Emoji. It is similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> that allows you to enter an arbitrary character by specifying its Unicode number. Here, instead of a number, you specify an Emoji name, like "kiss", "grin" or "<3".

Comment: Hm.  Since it's part of the application, it looks like I can't disable it.  Oh well.

Comment: I don't see anything about ctrl-shift-E there?

Comment: @nafg Page has changed. Added the archived version to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! (Do you know if this is an older behavior that was hardcoded, or if it's just mentioning the default ibus setting as in the other answer?)

Comment: No, I really don't know @nafg